# C# Selenium - Check text on web page

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath

The below function is what I have been using to check texts on web pages, but the function fails to find text put under 'br' tag. Kindly advice.

C#:

```
 public static IWebElement CheckTextOnPage(IWebDriver driver, string _text)
    {
        var buildXpath = "//*[contains(translate(text()[normalize-space()],'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), '" + _text.ToLower() + "' )]";
        return driver.FindElement(By.XPath(buildXpath));
    }
```

Sample Html:

```
<html>
<div>
Test string 1.
<br>Test string 2.
<br>Test string 3.
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you post Relevant HTML?

Comment: `_text.ToLower()` what value this is ? if your value is  `Test string 2.`  this won't work?

Comment: XPath problem ? As @KunduK stated, please provide html code. You can try this alternate XPath expression : `//text()[normalize-space()][contains(translate(.,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), '" + _text.ToLower() + "' )]/parent::*`

Comment: @E.Wiest - Yeah! this is what I tried and worked.

Comment: Nice. If everything's fine, you can mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this alternate XPath expression :

```
//text()[normalize-space()][contains(translate(.,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), '" + _text.ToLower() + "' )]/parent::*
```